# Devise do not generate rails standard URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this setup for Devise

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  :confirmations => "confirmations", 
  :registrations => "registrations"} do
     put "confirm_user", :to => "confirmations#confirm_user" 
  end
```

and when I run

```
rake route
```

I have get strange routes for registrations_controller specialy the edit_path

```
 edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             registrations#edit
                        PUT    /users(.:format)                  registrations#update
                        DELETE /users(.:format)                  registrations#destroy
```

The problem is edit url for example for first user.

I expected

```
/users/1/edit
```

but I have get

```
/users/edit.1
```

I expect this route can not work but it does. Now I am not sure if I have made some mistake or if the devise generate the routes this way.

And if it generate routes that way where goes the format of request?

I can not believe that the URL might look like this.

```
/users/edit.1.js
```

Thanks for any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am passing the id to the edit route but it doesn't expect an id.

The edit_user_registration_path is only for current_user so the user.id is unnecessary.

This question might be also helpful.

[Devise: Allow admins to edit other users - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578182/devise-allow-admins-to-edit-other-users-rails/5582660#5582660)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not related to the edit url, instead it depends on the page that is linking to the edit one. You have probably a link of this form

```
link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path(@user)
```

that point to the edit url, which generates the unexpected url

```
/users/edit.id
```

You simply have to replace the link omitting the @user, as

```
link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path
```

Comment: this is the correct answer since I would only allow modification of the settings of the user only if they are logged in.

Answer (score 1):

That `.` is always there when showing a format. It's nothing from Devise, and there's nothing wrong with it. You're all good!

Comment: As you wrote the dot should separate the format of request but no the id of record that I want to edit.