# Edit other user as admin in devise, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise in my Ruby on Rails project and users have an admin-attribute:

schema.rb:

```
     create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
       .

        t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
      end
```

I want, that an admin user can edit other users. I'm not the first one asking this question, but all the given answers lack clear instructions:

1. There is an entry in the devise wiki from 2011: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

But I don't understand what I need to do: It mentions `"devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'my'"` in the routes, but I don't have that in my routes. Then, it mentions, how I need to remove the password key of the params hash, but my users_controller is empty. No more instructions are provided.

2. There is a stackoverflow answer to this: [Devise: Allow admins to edit other users - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578182/devise-allow-admins-to-edit-other-users-rails)

But I don't fully understand, what needs to be done: I see, that I need to add `devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'`to my routes, but the poster talks also about building out your forms and controller on your own, and isolating the Userscontroller. I don't understand, what he means.

3. There is another stackoverflow answer: [Rails, Devise - Admin trying to edit another user profile, own profile loaded instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394822/rails-devise-admin-trying-to-edit-another-user-profile-own-profile-loaded-in?rq=1)

In this one, the poster uses cancan and it seems, he does have an admin class in his usercontroller, which I don't have:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Once again, I don't know, how the poster got there and what he did.

Is there a step-by-step guide, to let the admin-user edit other userprofiles?

You can access my code here: https://github.com/Metaphysiker/philosophica

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. add a prefix in routes on `devise_for :users,: :path_prefix => 'my'`
2. add this below devise_for: `resources :users`
3. copy edit.html.erb from the registration from devise to users.
4. Change `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>`

to: `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`

5. Add this to the usercontroller:

   ```
      def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end


      def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update(user_params)
          redirect_to adminpanel_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
   ```

Done. <strike>(strangely, I can't put number 5 in code)</strike>

Comment: I know it is an old question but isn't there a way to make it more DRY? With this solution I end up with 2 almost identical forms.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :( I'm getting the validation error "password can't be blank" when the user doesn't try to update the password.

Comment: @lucas I'm getting the same problem "password can't  be blank". Have you found a solution for this.