# Edit other users devise ruby on rails error undefined local variable or method resource_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im setting up a Landlord Management System and trying to manage other users. I currently have admin as a boolean attribute in my users model, so i would like to edit other users and make them admin via the edit form.

I am trying to do this via influence from this post [Edit other user as admin in devise, ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583473/edit-other-user-as-admin-in-devise-ruby-on-rails)

So Here is my code:

Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'my'
resources :users
```

views\users\edit

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>

<% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
  <p>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %> 
</p>
<% end %>

<%= f.input :password,
            hint: "leave it blank if you don't want to change it",
            required: false,
            input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation,
            required: false,
            input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
<%= f.input :admin,
            required: false %>
<%= f.input :current_password,
            hint: "we need your current password to confirm your changes",
            required: true,
            input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" } %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.button :submit, "Update" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", 
registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
method: :delete %></p>
```

controllers\users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end


def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update(user_params)
redirect_to adminpanel_path
else
render 'edit'
end
end

end
```

**Issue**

if i go to http://localhost:3000/users/2/edit to edit a user i get the following error
`undefined local variable or method resource_name for #<#<Class:0x8b9df40>:0x8ba7360>`

Comment: Why do you have `devise_for :users` and `resources :users`?

Comment: please see answer in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583473/edit-other-user-as-admin-in-devise-ruby-on-rail, this is what i was trying to implement

Comment: It looks like the `views\users\edit` code you show is the Devise code. Is that correct? If so, you seem to be mixing up the devise code and the users code you need.

Comment: hi @hashrocket yes that is correct that is what it said on previous post mentioned in question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583473/edit-other-user-as-admin-in-devise-ruby-on-rail, but i did change line 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
undefined local variable or method resource_name for #<#<Class:0x8b9df40>:0x8ba7360>
```

tells you that resource_name is undefined. Remove all resource references from your form and it will work. As for your cancel account link:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel my account", 
registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
method: :delete %></p>
```

you need to change resource_name to the user id you want to delete.

I've also seen you are using custom attributes for devise:

```
<%= f.input :admin,
            required: false %>
```

have you permitted them? Otherwise, this will be your next error. If you don't know how to do that, comment quickly and i'll update my answer.

Greetings!